# Gestouch works only when mapped to stage

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I am trying to use [gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch) library in my project and i can't seem to get it to work properly.

This is how i am mapping it:

```
var tapGesture:TapGesture = new TapGesture(stage);
tapGesture.addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_RECOGNIZED, onTap);
```

As you can see it is mapped to the stage and this way it works... 
The class where i am using it extends a flash Sprite, and i would like to map the gesture to 
`this`, but when i do, gestouch doesn't seem to work...

I even tried putting a sprite with stage width and height on top of my view and still doesn't work...

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Also, maybe it is important to note, i am using a ASC2.0, so i had to remove the mario mushroom operator from this part : `Gestouch.inputAdapter ||= new NativeInputAdapter(stage);`

Comment: How did you replace the mario mushroom operator?

Comment: Hmm, does your overlaped sprite have a visible area?

Comment: i replaced the mushroom operator with "=". The screen sprite is still empty. it has some vector graphics using the `graphics` from flash, and a bitmap

Comment: What's a mario mushroom operator?

Comment: @Ziul A Mario mushroom operator is ||= (it looks like a Super Mario mushroom on its side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (am the author of Gestouch) haven't tested it with ASC 2.0 because it's still in development, but yea, at least it's known that there issues with "mushroom operator" and -inline compiler argument.

So the answer: stick to MXMLC or use sources and find out why it doesn't work.

Also it is better to ask questions on Github. I found this almost by accident — Google reports me of Gestouch mentions =)

Comment: you can subscribe to gestouch feed on stackOwerflow